# How to get a specific line with python that contains and get the number on that line and divide it by 1000

Tags: python, vbscript

I'm making the most simple VBScript interpreter that ever existed only because I can try to make one. Python being a programming language and VBS being a scripting language VBS does not have the same capabilities. So it should be easy, or so I thought. My problem is because `WScript.sleep()` is in milliseconds as `time.sleep()` is in seconds.

```py
import  time
f = open("test.vbs", "r")
data = f.read()
data = new.replace("wscript.sleep("+number+")","wscript.sleep("+number/1000+")) #it should replace all numbers inside wscript.sleep with a number divided by 1000
new = new.replace("wscript.sleep", "time.sleep" )
```

```vb
msgbox("Hello!")
wscript.sleep(5000)
msgbox("This appears in 5 seconds!")
```

Just to let you know its a crapy interpreter not a full fledged. (and it runs in python)

Comment: So, what is your actual problem?

Comment: I vbs sleep is in miliseconds. python sleep is in seconds. I would like python to read the vbs sleep in seconds

Comment: IIRC, `time.sleep()` accepts decimal numbers like `0.5`, so just convert the milliseconds to a decimal number.

Comment: BTW, saying "Python being a programming language and VBS being a scripting language" is a pretty fast and loose definition. Both are programming languages and both can be used for jobs that we traditionally categorize as "scripting". Both are also interpreted. Python is newer and more appropriate for creating large programs. It's well suited for the educational purpose you propose, but, of course, a full-fledged interpreter should be written in a compiled language.

Comment: @LesFerch I don't really have to give you the definition as most people have a browser engine.

Comment: It's not about being able to look things up, it's just about making accurate statements. No big deal. Is your issue resolved? Did you feed `time.sleep()` a decimal number?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming

```
msgbox("Hello!")
wscript.sleep(5000)
msgbox("This appears in 5 seconds!")
```

is your input in the file, you can always use regex to match.
Read the file line by line,

```
num = re.match(r"(wscript.sleep\()(\d+)",s)[2]
n = str(float(num)/1000)
```

Then finally :

```
re.sub(r"(wscript.sleep\()(\d+)",lambda match: match.group(1) + n,s)
```

This would do the job, but may not be the efficient way to do it.